Git bash in windows-terminal Scandinavian characters causing problems
When running git bash in windows terminal (or wezterm) it acts weird when I mistype a Scandinavian character(æøå) followed by me deleting it with backspace.
It seems like there is a mismatch between what windows terminal displays and what is actually there.
Examples: (<bs> for backspace)
If I type "git statusæ<bs>" (windows terminal now displaying "git status")
The output will be "git: 'statusÃ' is not a git command. See 'git --help'."
If I type "git statusæ<bs><bs>" (windows terminal now displaying "git statu")
Result is it runs git status.
Other notes
It doesn't happen if I do the same in git bash itself, and it's not a problem when running powershell in windows terminal.
I've had similar results in WezTerm so it doesn't seem to be specific to windows terminal.
Are there some kind of encoding setting I can set either in git-bash or windows terminal to make what is displayed in the terminal match with what is happening in git-bash?
